# How can i keep update the targets array when destroying and creating new objects again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is in this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PatrolData
{
    public Transform target = null;
    public float minDistance = 5f;
    public float lingerDuration = 5f;

    public float desiredHeight = 10f;

    public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
    public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
    public float flightAcceleration = 1f;

    public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
    public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
    public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;
}

public class PatrolOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FlyToOverTerrain flyOverTerrain;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCamera;
    public enum PatrolMode { Clamp, Wrap, PingPong };
    public PatrolData[] patrolPoints;
    public PatrolMode mode = PatrolMode.Wrap;

    private int iterator = 0;
    private int index = 0;
    private float lingerDuration = 0f;
    private int oldLength = 0;

    public List<GameObject> TeleportationBooths = new List<GameObject>();
    public Vector3 distanceFromTarget;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] tempObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleportation Booth");

        for (int i = 0; i < tempObj.Length; i++)
        {
            //Add to list only if it does not exist
            if (!TeleportationBooths.Contains(tempObj[i]))
            {
                TeleportationBooths.Add(tempObj[i]);
            }
        }

        //Get the current Size
        if (tempObj != null)
        {
            oldLength = tempObj.Length;
        }

        GeneratePatrolPoints();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (patrolPoints.Length > 0)
        {
            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }
    }



    private void Update()
    {
        //Check if oldLength has changed
        if (oldLength != TeleportationBooths.Count)
        {
            //Update oldLength
            oldLength = TeleportationBooths.Count;

            //Call your the function
            GeneratePatrolPoints();
        }

        int length = patrolPoints.Length;
        if (!flyOverTerrain) return;
        if (patrolPoints.Length < 1) return;
        if (index < 0) return;

        // Getting exception out of index on line 89.
        // Need to make a list also for the Cubes(buildings).

        var patrol = patrolPoints[index];
        if (lingerDuration <= 0)
        {
            iterator++;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case PatrolMode.Clamp:
                    index = (iterator >= length) ? -1 : iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.Wrap:
                    iterator = Modulus(iterator, length);
                    index = iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.PingPong:
                    index = PingPong(iterator, length);
                    break;
            }
            if (index < 0) return;

            patrol = patrolPoints[index];

            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            flyOverTerrain.desiredHeight = patrol.desiredHeight;
            flyOverTerrain.flightSmoothTime = patrol.flightSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxFlightspeed = patrol.maxFlightspeed;
            flyOverTerrain.flightAcceleration = patrol.flightAcceleration;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingSmoothTime = patrol.levelingSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxLevelingSpeed = patrol.maxLevelingSpeed;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingAcceleration = patrol.levelingAcceleration;

            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.RotationSpeed = 3;

            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }


        Vector3 targetOffset = Vector3.zero;
        if ((bool)patrol.target)
        {
            targetOffset = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
        }

        float sqrDistance = patrol.minDistance * patrol.minDistance;
        if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = null;
            lookAtCamera.target = null;
            lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
        }
        distanceFromTarget = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
    }

    private int PingPong(int baseNumber, int limit)
    {
        if (limit < 2) return 0;
        return limit - Mathf.Abs(limit - Modulus(baseNumber, limit + (limit - 2)) - 1) - 1;
    }

    private int Modulus(int baseNumber, int modulus)
    {
        return (modulus == 0) ? baseNumber : baseNumber - modulus * (int)Mathf.Floor(baseNumber / (float)modulus);
    }

    public void GeneratePatrolPoints()
    {
        patrolPoints = new PatrolData[TeleportationBooths.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < patrolPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            patrolPoints[i] = new PatrolData();
            patrolPoints[i].target = TeleportationBooths[i].transform;
            patrolPoints[i].minDistance = 30f;
            patrolPoints[i].lingerDuration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightSmoothTime = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxFlightspeed = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightAcceleration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingAcceleration = 2f;
        }
    }
}
```

In this part inside the Update i'm comparing the old length of a list with the current length:

```
//Check if oldLength has changed
        if (oldLength != TeleportationBooths.Count)
        {
            //Update oldLength
            oldLength = TeleportationBooths.Count;

            //Call your the function
            GeneratePatrolPoints();
        }
```

So in case i create a new objects without destroying the old ones first it will be fine the length is not the same and it will call GeneratePatrolPoints() and will update the targets with the new targets just added:

```
patrolPoints[i].target = TeleportationBooths[i].transform;
```

The problem is when i check the ui toggle and first destroy the objects and then create them again the length is the same as before so it will not call GeneratePatrolPoints() and will not update the targets.

So i'm getting missing object exception.
I'm updating the list but i also need to update the targets again.

In this script i decide if the create new objects and to add them to the list so the length will not be the same and everything is right or to destroy first the current objects and then create new ones but then the length will be the same:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GenerateObjectsButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private InstantiateObjects[] instantiateobjects;
    private bool toggleOnOf;
    public Toggle toggle;

    private void Start()
    {
        toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
            {
                MyListener(value);
            });
    }

    public void MyListener(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            //do the stuff when the toggle is on
            toggleOnOf = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //do the stuff when the toggle is off
            toggleOnOf = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnButton()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < instantiateobjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (toggleOnOf == false)
            {
                instantiateobjects[i].generateObjectOnTerrain();
            }
            else
            {
                instantiateobjects[i].DestroyObjects();
                instantiateobjects[i].generateObjectOnTerrain();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the first script with comparing the length with the list count.

Comment: Ok found a working solution. Should i answer my own question ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a new bool variable in the GenerateObjectsButton script:

```
public bool destroyed = false;
```

And set it to true after destroying and creating new objects again:

```
public void OnButton()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < instantiateobjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (toggleOnOf == false)
            {
                instantiateobjects[i].generateObjectOnTerrain();
            }
            else
            {
                instantiateobjects[i].DestroyObjects();
                instantiateobjects[i].generateObjectOnTerrain();
                destroyed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now destroyed is true.
Back to the PatrolOverTerrain script.

Now i'm not only checking if the length is not the same but also if destroyed is true:

```
//Check if oldLength has changed
    if (oldLength != TeleportationBooths.Count)
    {
        //Update oldLength
        oldLength = TeleportationBooths.Count;

        //Call your the function
        GeneratePatrolPoints();
    }

    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Button");
    var destroyed = go.GetComponent<GenerateObjectsButton>().destroyed;
    if (destroyed)
    {
        GeneratePatrolPoints();
    }
```

Now i know when i only created new objects and added them by comparing length or when first destroyed the objects and then created new so the length didn't change but the list it self did.

Anyway this is a working solution.